# Derivation of the Differential Wave Equation in Textbook

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, wave-equation, chain-rule

I am reading *Optics* by Eugene Hecht, and I am confused about the author's derivation of the differential wave equation:

> To relate the space and time dependencies of $\psi(x, t)$, take the partial derivative of $\psi(x, t) = f(x')$ with respect to $x$, holding $t$ constant. Using $x' = x \mp vt$, and inasmuch as
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$$
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x'}} \dfrac{\partial{x'}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x'}} \tag{2.8}$$
>
> because $$\dfrac{\partial{x'}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{\partial{x \mp vt}}{\partial{x}} = 1$$
>
> Holding $x$ constant, the partial derivative with respect to time is
>
> $\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}} = \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x'}} \dfrac{\partial{x'}}{\partial{t}} = \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x'}} (\mp v) = \mp v \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x'}} \tag{2.9}$
>
> Combining Eqs. (2.8) and (2.9) yields
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}} = \mp v \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{x}}$$
>
> This says that the rate of change of $\psi$ with $t$ and with $x$ are equal, to within a multiplicative constant, as shown in Fig. 2.5. The second partial derivatives of Eqs. (2.8) and (2.9) are
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{x}^2} = \dfrac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x'}^2} \tag{2.10}$$
>
> and $$\dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{t}^2} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}} \left( \mp v \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x'}} \right) = \mp v \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x'}} \left( \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}} \right)$$
>
> Since $$\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}} = \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}}$$
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{t}^2} = \mp \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x'}} \left( \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}} \right)$$
>
> It follows, using Eqn. (2.9), that $$\dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{t}^2} = v^2 \dfrac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x'}^2}$$

I don't see how

$$\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}} = \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}} \tag{1}$$

We actually found that $\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}} = \mp v \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{x}}$, so I have no idea where the author got $\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}} = \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}}$ from?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: $$\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}} = \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{x}}\dfrac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}}+\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}}\dfrac{\partial{t}}{\partial{t}} = \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}}$$
but $$\dfrac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}}=0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\psi(x, t) = f(\bar{x}) \to \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x, t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(\bar{x})
$$
this is true. The fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(\bar{x})$ also equals something else is secondary.